# Iphone, for regularly updated data is NSUserDefaults still the easiest option?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have been designing my app to store local user data which is changed / sorted and referenced regularly to be stored as global variables held by the app delegate and referenced through:

```
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]
```

Which seems to work though is most likely not best practice, is there any downsides to just holding the same data in NSUserDefaults, SQL Lite seems a bit heavy for my needs considering the data itself is a couple of small arrays of custom objects and is refreshed on start up and throughout the app.

Is there a general best practice for local storage, or does it really depend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using Core Data. Although the first experience may be a little confusing, the investment will be worth it.

Comment: & @DavidM: Yeah and not to forget the first attempt would look to be tough but once you get grip of that. Then you can play with it at the tip of your fingers. So certainly worth the investment. Great answer by `mvds`

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is fine. A better practice would probably be to have a singleton class that contains all the related data. Then anywhere you need the day you just call [[globalData instance] arrayOfData] and have it. That way you abstract the data from your app delegate into a centralized place.

NSUserDefaults is used to store information between app launches. Use it to store settings or things that you read each time the app launches or use it to save the state of the app so a user can relaunch and be in the same place after they exited. There isn't really any noticeable performance issues unless the data you are storing is rather large.

Answer (score 0):

> for my needs considering the data
>   itself is a couple of small arrays of
>   custom objects and is refreshed on
>   start up and throughout the app.

As your current requirements are limited to small arrays and custom objects, NSUserDefaults could be used.

But while using NSUserDefault we should take care of these two facts.
1.) For custom object you will need to use Encoding Protocols for directly saving them using NSUserDeraults.

2.) NSUserDefaults some times shows strange behavior if we don't synchronize it properly. you can use its `[NSUserDefaults synchronize].

Core Data should be used when you are working many with interrelated custom objects. Because its concept of object relationship mapping and direct object management is quite good.{at lower layer it uses SQLite}.

SQLite on the other hand is relatively easy to implement and has C api for interaction with system. Here you will need to break down custom object into attributes and run queries.